# Selenium script to remove selected page likes from Facebook page

Tags: python, facebook, selenium

I'm looking for a script or example of script which traverses through list of users liking a Facebook page I administer and removes likes meeting some simple criteria (e.g. country). Maybe some selenium code?

Has somebody seen something like that over the web, or maybe somebody could share some code?

Comment: How do you plan to identify that criterion? I don't know what an administrator's-eye-view of a FB page looks like - can you see any information about the liking users other than their names? If not, are you willing to programmatically access each user's page to extract that information?

Comment: the question is: would that even be allowed? and who would want to run a such a script?

Comment: Using Selenium for this, you are making it way too awkward! Use the FB API instead.

Comment: it´s not possible to unlike pages with the facebook api

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish that with selenium. But, begin with the selenium Firefox extension to record the scenario you want and then convert it to a python script
for more info I recommend you to read [this docs](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp)

Comment: if you just want to tell him that it IS possible with selenium, better write a comment instead of an answer. i assume if he knows about selenium, he knows about the firefox extension too.